# What is the syntax for PC-Lint ( In Scan for compiler warning) in jenkins Pipeline

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, pc-lint

I have started porting my existing `Jenkins` job to `Jenkins` `Pipeline`.
When it came to port the `Scan for compiler warning` in `Post-build action`, I started getting issues.
First I tried to port `PC-Lint`. Used the following code

```
stage ('Warnings pclint') {
    steps {
        timeout(time: 5, unit: 'MINUTES') {
            sh 'npm run lint:ci'
            step([$class: 'WarningsPublisher',
                parserConfigurations: [[
                    parserName: 'PC-Lint',
                    pattern: 'pmd.xml'
                ]],
                unstableTotalAll: '0',
                usePreviousBuildAsReference: true
            ])
        }
    }
}
```

But it didn't work. What is wrong in this ?
Is there any other way to do this ?

Answer (score 1):

After searching a lot finally I got a working syntax.

```
step([$class: 'WarningsPublisher',
                consoleParsers: [[parserName:'PC-Lint']],
                defaultEncoding: '',
                excludePattern: '',
                healthy: '',
                includePattern: '',
                messagesPattern: '',
                unHealthy: '',
                useStableBuildAsReference: true
            ])
```

It is good to have this in the post build section of the `Pipeline`